# Java Stream Map Filter, Remove and Collect

Tags: java, collections, java-stream

I have a `Map` with 1000 items and I want to generate a `List` from the first 500 items of this `Map` and remove the items that was collected from the `Map`.

In other words, I want to filter, collect to a `List` and remove items from a `Map`.

I'm trying something like that:

```java
final int i = 0;
int max = 5;
Map<String, Object> map = new HashMap<>();
map.put("ads", "123");
map.put("qwe", "123");
map.put("cvb", "123");
map.put("asd", "123");
map.put("iop", "123");
map.put("jkl", "123");
map.put("yui", "123");

List list = map.entrySet().stream().filter(y -> i++ < max).collect(Collectors.toList());
```

Expected output:

Map with 2 Values

List with 5 Values

Comment: It's not clear what you want to do, and the posted code doesn't compile to begin with. Please provide a sample input and expected output of what you want to do, for example with just 10 elements.

Comment: Note that you cannot use the Stream any more after executing a terminal operation like `.collect` or `.forEach`.

Comment: @ÓscarLópez thanks for you feedback, i made some changes to the question and add an input and output.

Comment: Also, _do_ notice that an `entrySet()` makes no guarantees about the order of its elements. They are not necessarily the first five you added, _unless_ you're using a `LinkedHashMap`. But in general, the idea of taking "the first n elements" from a map doesn't make sense, if the order is important perhaps you should use a different data structure.

Comment: And final means `i` can't be changed once assigned.  So you can't do this `filter(y -> i++ < max).`  And even if you didn't declare `i` final, local variables must be effectively final in lambdas.

Comment: @naman the duplicate does not answer the question

Comment: @YassinHajaj the duplicate gives the way to solve the question for sure as it states the approach of identifying "first N elements" from a map.. anyway, it's kind of an opinion that individuals have and there is nothing more than that in the question according to me. (i.e. `removeIf` is just *not even clearly* a part of the question.)

Comment: @Naman look at the example he's giving, it clearly states that the map should have less items in the end

Answer (score 7):

Stream API intended to create a new collection, but not to change existing collection, from which a stream created.

It's better use iterator feature in this situation. Like this:

```
final int MAX = 500;

Map<String, String> map = new HashMap<>();
map.put("Item1", "Item 1 value");
map.put("Item2", "Item 2 value");
// ...
map.put("Item1000", "Item 1000 value");

List<String> list = new ArrayList<>();


var iterator = map.entrySet().iterator();
for (int i = 0; i< MAX; i++) {
  if (iterator.hasNext()) {
    var item = iterator.next();
    list.add(item.getValue());
    iterator.remove();
  }
}
```

Comment: Works fine with `LinkedHashMap` for getting the first `MAX` items. See comment about this question of Óscar López.

Comment: Using iterator garantee removing exactly same entries that added to list. No matters LinkedHashMap or HashMap.

Comment: yes you are right about the `Iterator`, and `LinkedHashMap` garantee removing the first 500 inserted items from the map.

Comment: There is no need to iterate over the `entrySet()` to call `getValue()` on each entry. You can simply use `values()` in the first place, `var iterator = map.values().iterator(); for(int i = 0; i < MAX && iterator.hasNext(); i++) { list.add(iterator.next()); iterator.remove(); }`

Comment: Underlying mechanisms for the both iterators backed by the same map. So there is no performance benefit of values().iterator() over entrySet().iterator. But entrySet().iterator() also allows you get access to the entry key.

Answer (score 0):

As pointed out in other answer and comments you cannot alter the map during the streaming operations. So this requires two steps.

```
var list = map.keySet().stream().limit(500).toList();
map.keySet().removeAll(list);
```

I've used Java 16 API here but previous versions are minor variations.

Note, however, that is is a pretty meaningless thing to do given the map's order is not defined. It would be more meaningful if you were using a filter with some predicate. Though in that case a more readable alternative might be:

```
var list = map.keySet().stream().filter(predicate).toList();
map.keySet().removeIf(predicate);
```

Comment: Or `var list = new ArrayList<String>(); map.keySet().removeIf(predicate.and(list::add));`

Answer (score 0):

The easiest way to achieve this with ***A SINGLE STREAM*** is to use `Stream#limit`, `Collectors#collectingAndThen` and perform the `removeAll` inside of the second downstream `Collector`

This is possible because the first `Collectors.toList` will get rid of the map's iteration, the second operation can then delete without getting an exception

```
List<Map.Entry<String, Object>> list = map.entrySet()
        .stream()
        .limit(max)
        .collect(Collectors.collectingAndThen(
                Collectors.toList(),
                l -> {
                    map.entrySet().removeAll(l);
                    return l;
                }
        ));

System.out.println("map = " + map); // map = {qwe=123, cvb=123}
System.out.println("list = " + list); // list = [ads=123, asd=123, jkl=123, iop=123, yui=123]
```

Comment: one of the reasons why I marked it duplicate was `.entrySet().stream().limit(max)` doesn't guarantee the "first `max` elements". would like to point you to [Oscar's comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67452611/java-stream-map-filter-remove-and-collect#comment119224194_67452611).

Comment: Instead of `removeIf(l::contains)` you can use the good old `removeAll(l)`

Comment: Is there any advantage in doing the `removeAll` as the collector finisher rather than as a separate statement afterwards? Seems unnecessarily verbose to use a lambda block here (and has the risks associated with lambda operations having side effects).

Comment: Having a one liner is the idea here. What kind of side effects would you imagine sprinter ?